# Calling webservice when listview is clicked then update expanded listview?

Tags: android, android-library

I am developing listview like a accordian view so for that i got library from this [a link](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView) and please see this link for answer to question. now i am Implemented this library successfully but what i want is when user click on one of the listview then listview expanded data will update from web server. In slideexpanded library they given one listener and i am not able to use this custom listener perfectly.

```
//this listener for listview

 listSlide.setItemActionListener(new ActionSlideExpandableListView.OnActionClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View listView, View buttonview, int position) {

            unitId = hm.get(position);
            Log.v("Bunglow list", "data-"+unitId);
            Toast.makeText(
                    BungalowsDetailActivity.this,
                    "Clicked Action: "+unitId+" in list item "+position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();   

            /**
             * Here call webservice and get data from server 
             * then update expanded view
             **/
            //new LoadDataFrmSrvr().execute();


            String actionName = "";
            if(buttonview.getId() == R.id.bangDetbuttonA) {

                actionName = "Button A is Clicked";
            } 
            else {
                actionName = "Button B is Clicked";
            }
            *//**
             * For testing sake just show a toast
             *//*
            Toast.makeText(
                    BungalowsDetailActivity.this,
                    "Clicked Action: "+actionName+" in list item "+position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
        }

        // note that we also add 1 or more ids to the setItemActionListener

    }, R.id.bangDetbuttonA, R.id.bangDetbuttonB);
```

My requirement is when i will clicked on listview first display listview toast then call webservice but this won't happen in my case once listview is expanded and then if i clicked on expanded list or element then first toast was displayed then expanded list toast was displayed. i want to call web service when i clicked on listview and after that all expanded data will display. please see following two fig. 
Please anybody suggest me answer because i tried from yesterday but not achieve my goal and if somebody already use this library for listview like accordian so please help me.

fig 1 shows list

[image]

fig 2 shows expanded list

[image]